# Javascript - Functions, missing argument

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, conditional-statements

Baby coder here, just getting into functions. I've created a function to calculate the area of a rectangle, and it works as long as two arguments are provided. I want my code to assume the shape is a square (so length and width are equal), if only one argument is provided. I've been trying to come up with a conditional, but don't know how to say "if there is only one argument, then length === width". Any pointers appreciated!

```js
function area(length, width) {
    let rectangleArea = Number(length) * Number(width);
    return rectangleArea;
}
console.log(area(10, 5));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to use a [default function parameters](https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) for the `width` parameter and set it to `length` if it is not passed

```js
function area(length, width = length) {
  let rectangleArea = length * width;
  return rectangleArea;
}

console.log(area(10, 5));
console.log(area(10));
```

Default function parameters is a recent feature. If it is confusing, you could check if `width` parameter is `undefined` and set it to `length`

```js
function area(length, width) {
  if (typeof width === "undefined")
    width = length;

  let rectangleArea = length * width;
  return rectangleArea;
}

console.log(area(10, 5));
console.log(area(10))
```

Also, the `Number()` wrapper is not required here. You are already passing numbers. Even if you pass strings as parameters like `area("10", "5")`, they are coerced to numbers and multiplied.

Comment: I ended up using the second one, just to avoid confusing myself, but I think I understand why the first works, too. Thank you!

Comment: @tarabyte you're welcome. If the answer resolved your issue, please [mark it as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289255) by clicking on the grey checkmark on the left

Answer (score 2):

You may use default parameter `width = length`. If the value of `width` is not passed to the function, the value of `length` will be assigned to the `width`.

```js
function area(length, width = length) {
    let rectangleArea = Number(length) * Number(width);
    return rectangleArea;
}

console.log(area(10, 5));
console.log(area(10));
console.log(area(5));
```